# closest() not selecting the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
  <h2 class="tm section-title margin-l-10">Normal Cards<button class="tm bg-dark btn-tiny margin-b-10 float-r js-show-code">show code</button></h2>
    <div class="grid-100">
      <code>
        &lt;div class=&quot;<span class="tm bg-win blue">tm card</span>&quot;&gt;
          <span class="tm lightyellow">...</span>
        &lt;/div&gt;
      </code>
    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT (*jQuery*)**

```
$('.js-show-code').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('code').slideToggle()
});
```

I'm still learning Javascript and Jquery, and I have no clue what i'm doing wrong. I can't select the `<code>`

It always returns: `[prevObject: r.fn.init[1]]`

Comment: .closest is used to find closest parent of respective element, and <code> is not the parent of .js-show-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest()` get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. You are looking for an element which is not related with `button.js-show-code`.

Try

```
 $('.js-show-code').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('h2').next(".grid-100").find("code").slideToggle()
    });
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qnrbutt/)

Answer (score 2):

**[`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** is used to find `closest` parent of respective `element`. Your button is wrapped inside a `h2` element and `closest` to that `button` would be `h2` and hence navigating in reverse direction of `parents`. You have wrong understanding about how `.closest` works. What you need to do is, navigate to `h2` with `closest('h2')` and get its `next` element and `find` required `code` element as per present `DOM` structure you have. Below is the `snippet`.

```js
$('.js-show-code').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('h2').next().slideToggle()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="tm section-title margin-l-10">Normal Cards<button class="tm bg-dark btn-tiny margin-b-10 float-r js-show-code">show code</button></h2>
<div class="grid-100">
  <code>
        &lt;div class=&quot;<span class="tm bg-win blue">tm card</span>&quot;&gt;
          <span class="tm lightyellow">...</span>
        &lt;/div&gt;
      </code>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought the same, but I tried with parent().closest() and didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: You are selecting the `div` element with `grid-100` class, not the `code` element as requested

Comment: @aKiRa as I said, this solution is for current DOM structure.. So doesn't really matter..

Answer (score 0):

.closest() traverses upwards in the dom, and therefore it will never reach the code element. If you have to use $(this) to find the code element you can do the following:

```
$('.js-show-code').click(function(){ 
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('code').slideToggle();
});
```

OR do it like this (wrap the whole thing in a container):

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="tm section-title margin-l-10">Normal Cards
    <button class="tm bg-dark btn-tiny margin-b-10 float-r js-show-code">show code
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div class="grid-100">
    <code>
      <span class="tm bg-win blue">tmcard</span>
      <span class="tm lightyellow">...</span>
    </code>
  </div>
</div>


$('.js-show-code').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('container').find('code').slideToggle();
});
```